# Need help in identifying where Memory leak is happening?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, micrometer

I am working on a springboot service which is using micrometer for getting stats. But service is getting OutOfMemoryError. I need help in identifying where the memory leak is happening.

Since its a big service I can'nt go through the whole code.

Any metrices I can add to see which service/class/object is creating the issue ?

Can't share the code with other 3rd party services.

Comment: First a code checker (SonarQube or whatever); this will be most helpful in general. OOM could also come from infinite recursion or  whatever. But then there would be a clear stacktrace. A dump of the remaining heap objects can be done.

Comment: Hey wont be able to put the code on any other 3rd party services. can you explain more on the "dump of the remaining heap objects can be done". How will this help in identifying the error code

Comment: You could look what objects did survive. Also installing Java Melody would be helpful, But the easiest measure is to have a code style checker find bugs (FindBugs, SonarLint and such). In IntelliJ IDEA (for instance Community Edition) there is a nice code analysis. Maybe it is something obvious, and code improvements cannot hurt.